# a pyinstaller problem in the python project using pypeteer

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I used **python pyinstaller** to build a python program using **pypeteer lib**, it worked in my **pycharm environment**, but it didn't work in the **exe** type. When it reached the function `page.goto()`,it showed me a bug: **invalid url**.

My code:

```
from pyppeteer.launcher import launch
    import asyncio

async def main(url):
    
    #..........

    print(f"url===>{url}")
    await page.goto(url)
```

When I run it, it shows the following error:

```
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
  File "main.py", line 71, in`your text` main
    await page.goto(url)
```

Is there anyone who also had this problem or anyone who knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the mistake in my config file was the reason behind the error. The correct format for the URL should be `url = https://xxxxx/index.jsp`, but I mistakenly wrote it as `url = 'https://xxxxx/index.jsp'`.

As a result, the terminal output was not providing the expected advice, but now it works correctly after fixing the configuration.